# Adding optgroups dynamically using jQuery

Tags: jquery, list

```
<select id="myElement" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="1">Category Type</option>
  <option value="158">itemOne</option>
  <option value="157">itemTwo</option>
  <option value="7">My Type</option>
  <option value="20">itemThree</option>
  <option value="21">itemFour</option>
  <option value="22">itemFive</option>
  <option value="8">Category Yet Another</option>
  <option value="31">itemCheese</option>
  <option value="32">itemBrain</option>
</select>
```

I need to dynamically convert this so that "Category" options (anything that doesn't start with "item") is an optgroup, wrapping whaterver comes after it until the next Category option, so the above would end up looking like:

```
<select id="myElement" multiple="multiple">
  <optGroup label="Category Type">
    <option value="158">One</option>
    <option value="157">Two</option>
  </optGroup>
  <optGroup label="My Type">
    <option value="20">Three</option>
    <option value="21">Four</option>
    <option value="22">Five</option>
  </optGroup>
  <optGroup label="Category Yet Another">
    <option value="31">Cheese</option>
    <option value="32">Brain</option>
  </optGroup>
</select>
```

How can I iterate over this and change values to acheive the desired effect using jQuery?

Comment: Solution: Refer  http://jsbin.com/nagohevoyi/1/edit?html,js,output     `AJS.$("#select2-example").append('<optgroup id="opt-gr1" label="Group test"></optgroup>');
AJS.$("#opt-gr1").append('<option>test</option>');
AJS.$("#opt-gr1").append('<option>test2</option>');`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have to iterate over the `option` elements and group them based on their contents. Using jQuery makes it way easier than just pure DOM API:

http://jsfiddle.net/kpykoahe/2/

```
$(document).ready(() => {
    const $cont = $('select');
    $('option').each((idx, el) => {
        const $el = $(el);
        if ($el.text().startsWith('item')) {
            $cont.find('optgroup').last().append($el);
            $el.text($el.text().substr(4));
        } else {
            $('<optgroup/>').attr('label', $el.text()).appendTo($cont);
            $el.remove();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to match the `<option>` elements that will become groups. Then, you can iterate over them and call [nextUntil()](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) on the same element set to match the subsequent options (as `nextUntil()` will stop when it encounters a member of the set, i.e. the next option that should become a group).

From there, you can use [wrapAll()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/) on these `<option>` elements to create their `<optgroup>` element, then call [remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) on the `<option>` element that just became a group. Something like:

```
var $groups = $("#myElement option").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().indexOf("item") != 0;
});
$groups.each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.nextUntil($groups).wrapAll($("<optgroup>", {
        label: $this.text()
    })).end().remove();
});
```

You can see the results in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/df7KQ/).

Comment: I like the use of wrapAll -- I wasn't sure how to use it if I didn't know beforehand which elements were going to go into (I saw an example where the number of items to be added to an optgroup were fixed).  Thanks a lot.

Comment: +1 this approach worked for me, however it only worked after doing a refresh on the multiselect - $("#myElement").multiselect('refresh'); so this might save someone else half a day of head scratching

Answer (score 2):

My implementation:

```
$(function(){
    var target = $('#target'),
        optGroup;

    function strStartsWith(str, prefix) {
        return str.indexOf(prefix) === 0;
    }

    $('#myElement').find('option').each(function(){
        var elm = $(this).clone();
        if(strStartsWith(elm.text(), 'item'))
        {
            elm.text(elm.text().substr(4));
            if(optGroup) optGroup.append(elm);
        }
        else
        {
            optGroup = $('<optgroup>').attr('label', elm.text());
            target.append(optGroup);
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HUHRz/1/

Answer (score 2):

```
$.each(data, function () {

    if (prevGroupName.indexOf(this.Group.Name) == -1) {
        $prevGroup = $('<optgroup />').prop('label', this.Group.Name).appendTo('#ConfigurationId');
    } else {
        $prevGroup = $("optgroup[label='" + this.Group.Name + "']");
    }
    $("<option />").val(this.Value).text(this.Text).appendTo($prevGroup);
    prevGroupName.push(this.Group.Name);
});
```